# CSS/HTML :: alignment and button problem under IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, button, alignment

i have a weird bug on this page when browsing with IE
http://www.emfx.fr/?page_id=38

this image explain clearly the problem :
http://appartager.free.fr/site/bugIE.jpg

- when i look at this page localy(easyPHP) with IE everything is OK
- when i look at this page online with IE i have 2 problem
  1) **my hr tag don't align to center** 
  2) **the button send message is crop**

BUT the **code is exactly the same** and the **Browser is the same** (IE)

the **hr** behavior is control in a css file

```
hr.center {
    border: none;
    color: #353a40;
    background-color: #353a40;
    height: 1px;
    width: 371px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

the **button** is also control by 2 css file (All Browser/IE exception)

here is the *general code* :

```
#contact_form input[type=submit] {
padding: 7px 15px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
font-family: "Droid Sans", Arial;
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid #666;
color: #ccc;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 420px;
}
```

here is the *ie exception*

```
#contact_form input[type=submit] {
    padding: 8px 0px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    margin-left: 418px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

if you guys have any idea on how to solve this it would be great !

cheers !

sk

Comment: please specify the version of IE you're testing with.

Answer (score 0):

You've removed the horizontal padding from the button in IE

```
#contact_form input[type=submit] {
    padding: 8px 0px; /* 15px?*/
```

and I'd personally center a `hr` using `margin:auto` instead of using `text-align` - but `hr` is aligned to the center by default; so you shouldn't need to adjust this.

(Taking those declarations out in IE web developer tools appears to resolve the problem).

Comment: Thanks a lot ross you solve all my problems ! i am not an expert in web dev so it's more trial and error in my case until it works :) And all you're suggestion were right ! Thanks again !